# Is it impossible to fit HC4 robust method for linear mixed models?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity

I've been struggling all day to fit a robust **HC4** model to my `lmer` in R (all the examples I've seen were with `lm`. I simply cannot find a way to do that, so **I've started wondering if theoretically it makes sense to do so** ? If not, what would be the 'correct' robust estimator for `lmers` for dealing with heteroscedasticity?

- I tried `parameters`, but the package doesn't seem to work for lmers:

```
library(lme4)]
library(lmerTest)
## the model:

a <- lmer(SCORE ~ type + (1|ID), data = dfModels1Filtered, REML = F)

### all students took 3 tests. Hence, each std has 3 scores based on type of test.

## what I've tried: 

parameters::parameters(a, robust = T, vcov.type = "HC4")

## the warning: 

Warning: The `robust` argument is deprecated. Please use `vcov` instead.Error: Unable to extract a variance-covariance matrix for model object of class
`lmerModLmerTest`. Different values of the `vcov` argument trigger calls to the
`sandwich` or `clubSandwich` packages in order to extract the matrix (see
  `?insight::get_varcov`). Your model or the requested estimation type may not be
  supported by one or both of those packages, or you were missing one or more
  required arguments in `vcov_args` (like `cluster`).
```

- I also tried [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/vignettes/tab_model_robust.html)
- **Q1:** but I wonder if it's actually performing a robust fit since I get the very exact CI, t and p as `summary` , so I don't know if it is indeed estimating a robust model
- **Q2**: I tried to write 'HC4', what would be "CR1" (the default in the documentation) ?

```
model_parameters(a, 
  ### vcov.fun = "CR1", 
  vcov.type = "HC4",
  vcov.args = list(cluster = dfModels1Filtered$ID))
```

- I can provide the data if necessary. Thanks in advance.